# Web site doesn't work on windows azure

Tags: azure, web

I deployed site on windows azure. It shows first simple page, but it loads too long. And it don't show more complicated pages, for example, with db quering. 
502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.

It seems like the problem in ARR, becouse i faced with similar problem when i tried to forward http request to another server. I just turned off reversed proxy. But i can't manage iis on azure.

There are exectly no problem with connections to db and no errors on the page.
Site is not public yet. It's on *****.azurewebsites.net. It uses MVC5 and azure SQL.

Comment: This is really a vague problem statement. Please edit your question to provide more concrete details. I don't see how this can be answered in its current state. Also: I don't see the relevance of the discussion around ARR and reverse-proxy, since (unless I misunderstood something), this isn't part of your current deployment.

Comment: As i said, no problem with front-end, the site is simple, as VS MVC start project. It works fine on any other places. It works on IIS express with connection to db on asure. I mentioned db just to say, that not working pages little bit complecated than just html. But home page of the start template is loaded too long. It seems like the problem not in my code at all but in infrastructure of asure. Maybe in farm off the asure. Like the request go somewhere else but not to my site.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague.

That said, you are using Azure Web Sites (WAWS).  If your page takes a long time to respond, eventually the front-end of WAWS will give up and return a 502 to the client. This front-end is part of WAWS's architecture and cannot be "turned off". This behavior usually indicates that there is something wrong with your page, perhaps:

1) The DB query are doing is slow.
2) The DB you are connecting to is in a different data center than your web page and therefore you're encountering slow-downs because of this.

But this is just stabbing in the dark without more context.  You can enable failed request tracing to help find the issue.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2013/08/01/enabling-failed-request-logging-on-a-windows-azure-web-site.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found that there was sql request if(...any()) by EF in global.asax. And if move it to controller, the problem disappears. It is strange and not logical. Maybe there are some limits to use EF on asure?